I'm looking for a Python script to convert DBF files stored in an Azure Storage account to Excel format using a custom activity in Azure Data Factory
In my scenario, DBF and FPT (memo file) will reside in Azure Blob Storage, and I aim to convert all DBF files to Excel using a VM in an Azure Batch account. After the conversion, I intend to upload the Excel files back to Blob Storage.
I want to convert DBF files to Excel
